# Change marker icon and a pop-up message closes

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm using leaflet.awesome-markers card markers. When you change the color of the icon it immediately closes the pop-up message.

Is it possible to change the color without closing the pop-up?

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.viewMap.click', function(e, args){
    $scope.selectedPoint = $scope.points.filter( function(spoint){ return spoint._id ===  args.modelName; })[0];
    $scope.waypoints[$scope.selectedPoint._id].icon.markerColor = 'green'; 
});
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: This can be observed even in the examples http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/markers/icons-example

Comment: what if you do a e.preventDefault();  before $scope.selectedPoint?

Comment: Also apply this decision (  e.preventDefault();) and to no avail . But the problem is not in this event - is not observed without changing the marker problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`L.Marker.setIcon()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#marker-seticon) instead, and stop propagation of the event, preferably with [`L.DomEvent.stop()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#domevent-stop) as it will stop propagation of `click` events from the marker to the map (through any `L.LayerGroups`, if any).

In plain Javascript (no angular) this would be:

```
marker.on('click', function(ev) {
    marker.setIcon(L.icon({ iconUrl: 'some-green-icon.png' }));
    // Also this.setIcon(...)

    L.DomEvent.stop(ev);    
});
```

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: The problem is that the event is opening pop-up window appears before clicking on the marker, so that it does not solve the problem. Although the decision has found for itself. Later, I will share.

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I solved the problem of the so - add and display pop-ups when necessary without using a standard mechanism angular (specified for a message marker).
You can of course was immediately initialize the pop-up messages when loading data, but in my project it easier to implement on-demand.

```
//popup's store
$scope.popups = {};

$scope._setViewMarker = function(pId, showPopup){
var wp = $scope.waypoints;
wp[pId].icon.markerColor = 'red';

//set unselected markers color
for (var i in wp)
    if(i != pId){
        wp[i].icon.markerColor = 'blue';
    };  
// close other popups
for (var i in $scope.popups)
    if(i != pId)
        $scope.map.closePopup($scope.popups[i]);        
// show or create poupap
if(showPopup)
    if($scope.popups[pId] ){
        if(!$scope.popups[pId]._isOpen)
            $scope.map.openPopup($scope.popups[pId]);
    } else {
        var ind = $scope.points.map(function(e) { return e._id; }).indexOf(pId);   
        var c = angular.element('<popup point="points['+ind+']" note-click="showDetailPoint(points['+ind+'])"></popup>');
        var linkFn = $compile(c);
        var element = linkFn($scope);
        $scope.popups[pId] = L.popup({offset:[0, -30]}).setLatLng( [wp[pId].lat, wp[pId].lng] ).setContent(element[0]).openOn($scope.map);
        $scope.popups[pId].pointId = pId;
    };
};    
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.viewMap.click', function(e, args){
    $scope._setViewMarker(args.modelName, true);
});
```